# ImageMagick on web server

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a controller in codeigniter that uploads images. Now for processing and cropping i use ImageMagick. I installed imageMagick on my mac and it works fine but i now i want it on my webserver. How can i install or what path do i need to use to get it working online? what i already tried is to put the map with the bin files on my server and locate the library path to it. But without success. Thanks.

Offline

```
$config['image_library'] = 'ImageMagick';
$config['library_path'] = 'opt/ImageMagick/bin/convert';
$config['source_image'] = $upload_data['full_path'];
$config['new_image'] = $gallery_path . '/thumbs';
$config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width'] = 350;
$config['height'] = 300;
```

Comment: It needs to be installed as a PHP extension. You could ask your hosting provider, or you could do it yourself if you have proper access to the machine

Answer (score 0):

You need to install PECL extension because it is not bundled with PHP.

According to the PHP documentation :

Information for installing this PECL extension may be found 
in the manual chapter titled [PECL extensions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php)

[Installation of Imagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php)

Comment: my website is running on the servers from one.com and imagick extension is not installed. I don't think i have permissions to install it any suggestions what i can might do then?

Comment: So You need to ask to one.com